# Can I grep telnet command output?

Tags: linux, telnet

I have a telnet command which prints hundreds of lines of output, Can I grep the output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the 'script' command. If you run 'script ' before running telnet, all text that gets written to the terminal also gets written to /file/path/filename. You'll have to do 'exit' or Ctrl-D to actually write to the file or you can keep a check on the file.

Finally grep on the file using filename | grep "search text"

/file/path/filename is the path where you want to store the output of telnet.

Using script command

```
script /tmp/myscript.txt
```

then all the commands you fire in terminal and the output will go in this file.
use ctrl + D when you are done, which will write to the file.

Do a grep on this file.

```
cat /tmp/myscript.txt | grep "textToSearch"
```

Comment: where is  /file/path/filename?

Comment: you have to set that.. where you want the output to go

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in Windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use `tee` command to redirect the content to file:

```
telnet google.com 80 | tee outfile
```

Then grep the file

Comment: Is there a way to do this from Perl script?

Answer (score -1):

To grep output from the network connection, you can use Bash shell instead of `telnet`, e.g.:

```
exec {stream}<>/dev/tcp/example.com/80
printf "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: example.com\nConnection: close\n\n" >&${stream}
grep Example <&${stream}
```